# Python error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable for HeadFirst Python code

Tags: python, module

I'm following the tutorial from the HeadFirst Python book. In chapter 7, I get an error message when trying to run the next code:

Athlete class:

```
class AthleteList(list):
    def __init__(self, a_name, a_dob=None, a_times=[]):
        list.__init__([])
        self.name = a_name
        self.dob = a_dob
        self.extend(a_times)

    def top3(self):
        return(sorted(set([sanitize(t) for t in self]))[0:3])

def get_coach_data(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = f.readline()
        templ = data.strip().split(',')
        return(AthleteList(templ.pop(0), templ.pop(0), templ))
    except IOError as ioerr:
        print('File error: ' + str(ioerr))
        return(None)

def sanitize(time_string):
    if '-' in time_string:
        splitter = '-'
    elif ':' in time_string:
        splitter = ':'
    else:
        return(time_string)
    (mins, secs) = time_string.split(splitter)
    return(mins + '.' + secs)
```

and with the next module I do some tests:

```
import pickle

import AthleteList

def get_coach_data(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = f.readline()
        templ = data.strip().split(',')
        return(AthleteList(templ.pop(0), templ.pop(0), templ))
    except IOError as ioerr:
        print('File error (get_coach_data): ' + str(ioerr))
        return(None)

def put_to_store(files_list):
    all_athletes = {}
    for each_file in files_list:
        ath = get_coach_data(each_file)
        all_athletes[ath.name] = ath
    try:
        with open('athletes.pickle', 'wb') as athf:
            pickle.dump(all_athletes, athf)
    except IOError as ioerr:
        print('File error (put_and_store): ' + str(ioerr))
    return(all_athletes)

def get_from_store():
    all_athletes = {}
    try:
        with open('athletes.pickle', 'rb') as athf:
            all_athletes = pickle.load(athf)
    except IOError as ioerr:
        print('File error (get_from_store): ' + str(ioerr))
    return(all_athletes)


print (dir())

the_files = ['sarah.txt','james.txt','mikey.txt','julie.txt']
data = put_to_store(the_files)

data
```

This is the content of the Julie.txt file:

```
Julie Jones,2002-8-17,2.59,2.11,2:11,2:23,3-10,2-23,3:10,3.21,3-21,3.01,3.02,2:59
```

and it's almost the same with the other files

I should get something like this output:

```
{'James Lee': ['2-34', '3:21', '2.34', '2.45', '3.01', '2:01', '2:01', '3:10', '2-22', '2-
01', '2.01', '2:16'], 'Sarah Sweeney': ['2:58', '2.58', '2:39', '2-25', '2-55', '2:54', '2.18',
'2:55', '2:55', '2:22', '2-21', '2.22'], 'Julie Jones': ['2.59', '2.11', '2:11', '2:23', '3-
10', '2-23', '3:10', '3.21', '3-21', '3.01', '3.02', '2:59'], 'Mikey McManus': ['2:22', '3.01',
'3:01', '3.02', '3:02', '3.02', '3:22', '2.49', '2:38', '2:40', '2.22', '2-31']}
```

but I get this error message:

```
['AthleteList', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'get_coach_data', 'get_from_store', 'pickle', 'put_to_store']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\workspace\HeadFirst\src\prueba.py", line 41, in <module>
    data = put_to_store(the_files)
  File "C:\Python\workspace\HeadFirst\src\prueba.py", line 19, in put_to_store
    ath = get_coach_data(each_file)
  File "C:\Python\workspace\HeadFirst\src\prueba.py", line 11, in get_coach_data
    return(AthleteList(templ.pop(0), templ.pop(0), templ))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah... I'm not going to give this question an upvote, but it certainly doesn't deserve a downvote. It's not a "please solve my homework for me" question.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your module and your class `AthleteList` have the same name.  The line

```
import AthleteList
```

imports the module and creates a name `AthleteList` in your current scope that points to the module object.  If you want to access the actual class, use

```
AthleteList.AthleteList
```

In particular, in the line

```
return(AthleteList(templ.pop(0), templ.pop(0), templ))
```

you are actually accessing the module object and not the class.  Try

```
return(AthleteList.AthleteList(templ.pop(0), templ.pop(0), templ))
```

Answer (score 14):

You module and class `AthleteList` have the same name. Change:

```
import AthleteList
```

to:

```
from AthleteList import AthleteList
```

This now means that you are importing the module object and will not be able to access any module methods you have in `AthleteList`

Answer (score 2):

As @Agam said,

You need this statement in your driver file:
   `from AthleteList import AtheleteList`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but I found it's caused by another reason: **the file of the imported class is in the same dir as the current file**.

For example, if my directory is:

- MyDir

  - __init__.py
  - MyClass.py
  - test.py

My __init__.py is:

```
from .MyClass import MyClass
__all__ = ['MyClass']
```

If I try to import MyClass in test.py as:

```
from MyDir import MyClass
```

the __init__.py won't work. It should be:

```
from MyClass import MyClass
```

I ignored they are in the same dir, so I write this to remind those who meet the same problem to check the path.